# jquery updating dynamic content

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have this html which is updated every 5th second from a json feed. I use dataTables plugin to add sort functionality for the columns. Therefore the order of the rows can vary

```
<table class="tablesorter-js">
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td class="bname-js">some content1</td>
      <td class="current-cont">some content2</td>
      <td> some content3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The json

```
{
  "some content1": {
     "pending": 1,
  }
}, // and so on
```

This is how I update the html

```
var tableRowList = $('.tablesorter-js tbody > tr');
var obj = JSON.parse(m);

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
  $(tableRowList).each(function(){
    // I compare the key of the of the json to the text in the first td           
    if (key === $('.bname-js',this).text().trim()) {
      $('.current-cont',this).html(value.pending);
    }
  });
});
```

This is very bad for the performance cause I loop through every tableRowList for every json key. Any suggestions to another approach ?

Comment: Perhaps you could give the `td` tags an id to search with? Or do you really have totally random data in a table with no control over it?

Comment: But I still have to loop through tableRowList for every key in the json?

Comment: Without knowing how the sort works and what kind of data you're dealing with, hard to comment on that. Any chance of being able to identify which row you're updating, so you can skip that loop?